# Calculate $10,000e^{-\int_2^{10}\left(0.05+0.01/(t+1)\right)\,dt}$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

This equation is used as an example in a text book with a given answer of $\approx$ 6,617

I cannot get to this solution as somewhere along the way I must be making an error. If it is a problem with the integration, please can you point out any fundamental things I'm doing wrong?

Sorry for all the fractions in the exponent, I tried to write it as clear as I could.

$$\begin{align}
& 10,000e^{-\int_2^{10}\left(0.05+\frac{0.01}{t+1}\right)\,dt} \\ \\
& 10,000e^{-\left[0.05t+0.01\frac{1}{0.5t^2+t}\ln|t+1|\right]_2^{10}} \\ \\
& 10,000e^{-\left[\left(0.05(10)+\frac{0.01}{0.5(10)^2+10}\ln11\right)-\left(0.05(2)(+\frac{0.01}{0.5(2)^2+2}\ln3\right)\right]} \\ \\ \\
& 10,000e^{-\left[\left(0.5+\frac{0.01}{60}\ln11\right)-\left(0.1+\frac{0.01}{4}\ln3\right)\right]}\\ \\
\approx& 6,719
\end{align}$$

Comment: There is no $t$-dependent factor for the logarithm. $\int_2^{10} \frac{dt}{1+t} = \log 11 - \log 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate $\frac{1}{t+1}dt$, use the substitution $u=t+1, du=dt$.  The integral becomes $\int\frac{1}{u}du=\ln|u|+C=\ln|t+1|+C$.  In context, $\int 0.05+\frac{0.01}{t+1}dt = \int 0.05dt + 0.01\int\frac{1}{t+1}dt=0.05t+0.01\ln |t+1|+C$.

Comment: Thanks, I've got myself confused over treating the $t+1$ in the denominator as another function and trying to integrate it as well.